# How can I encourage my boss to approve my work tasks?

Tags: management, follow-up

According to our company policy, I need to get my boss's comments and approval for each task to be able to do them. But since she's too busy usually my tasks get stuck in pending approval status and I have to follow up with her many times.

How can I tactfully ask my boss to approve my work items without irritating or bothering her too much?  I understand she's very busy, but I need my job to be done as well.

Comment: Can you elaborate: Is there some formal approval system, or does the approval/commentary happen in a ticketing system or other system? Does it need to be in writing? Or is there no specification on where/how the approval is supposed to happen?

Comment: Approval requires my boss's negotiation with other directors and then it happens in writing with comments for any changes

Answer (score 3):

If she's ignoring your approval queue, she will probably ignore the email, too.

If I were you, i'd knock on her door and ask:

> Hey, is there a good time to go over my approval queue? I think it will take about 30 minutes.

Answer (score 3):

Tell her that  your work is frequently stuck waiting for her approval. Ask her what work you should do while you are idle. Then do as she says.

Once she realises that her team member's time is not fully utilised, she will either have to figure out a way to fix the problem or make peace with the company's money being spent on keeping you idle.

There's nothing much you can do other than finding another job if your company finds the approval process so important that they are okay with paying the employees just for waiting.